# Volume of largest closed rectangular box

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I came across a question from this link: http://home.educities.edu.tw/ck870522/ad05.pdf, question 28, to be specific. I read through the answer, but i don't understand their explanation.Is there any other way to solve this question using Lagrange’s multipliers?

Question:

Find the volume of the largest closed rectangular box in the first octant
having three faces in the coordinate planes and a vertex on the plane $\frac{x}{a} + \frac{y}{b} + \frac{z}{c} = 1$, where $a > 0$ , $4b > 0$, and $c>0$.

Sorry, couldn't copy paste the answer here, the formatting is all over the place. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your link does not load.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 There was a problem with the site. Now, the link is working, I tried accessing it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to maximize $xyz$ given $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c}=1$.  The setup for Lagrange is
$$
yz=\frac{\lambda}{a},xz=\frac{\lambda}{b},xy=\frac{\lambda}{c}.
$$
Solving for $\lambda$ in each you get
$$
ayz=bxz=cxy.
$$
You can assume that all $x$, $y$, and $z$ are positive.

Comment: The part which i don't understand is g ( x, y, z ) = bcx + acy − abc = 0. Why is the z exempted?

Comment: @Phantom I am guessing that is a mistake.

Comment: Ah..so its bcx + acy - abz = 0? But, if that is the case why is it negative?

Comment: @Phantom It should be $bcx+acy+abz-abc=0$.

Comment: Okay! Thank you very much for your help :)